# $\lceil\ln(n)\rceil+\frac{(n-1)-\lceil\ln(n)\rceil}p\approx\frac{n}p$ when $n$ is much bigger than $p$. What do "much bigger" and $\approx$ mean here?

Tags: limits, asymptotics, approximation

In one book im reading, the author claim the following:

$$\lceil\ln(n)\rceil+\frac{(n-1)-\lceil\ln(n)\rceil}{p} \approx \frac{n}{p}$$

when ''$n$ is much bigger than $p$'' (both positive integers). The exact meaning of ''much bigger'' and $\approx$ (clearly indicating some sort of approximation) is not given, it is treated naturally because either it is obvious or it is assumed the reader is sophisticated enough to figure it out.

Before asserting the stated equivalence, the author surely had some tacit idea of what ''much bigger'' and $\approx$ means. What i would like to know is a reasonable definition for both concepts, so i can derive the result myself. I suspect that a possible definition for ''much bigger'' could be that $p/n$ tends to $\infty$, but i'm not sure how to compute with such a limit.

Comment: A likely meaning is that the ratio between the two sides of the $\approx$ approaches 1 as $n\to\infty$ (while $p$ is held constant or grows so that $\frac pn\to0$).

Comment: @Karl Yes, i known that as asymptotic equality, denoted by $\sim$. However, it looks like you need to known the right hand in advance to check both sides are indeed asymptotically equal.

Comment: @Karl Isn't this the same as saying the ratio between the two sides approaches 1 as $n \to 0$ while n is held constant?, i.e. "$p$ is much smaller than $n$".

Comment: Re your first comment: Yes, you "come up with" the RHS however you want (by inspection/intuition/experience) and then show that the limit statement is true. Different RHSs would work, but $n/p$ is (presumably) the simplest.

Comment: Re your second comment (assuming you mean $p\to0$): No, the $n\to\infty$ is what makes the $\log n$ in the numerator of the fraction become insignificant. Taking $p\to0$ wouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, we can look at the error we make when we replace the left side with the right side.  We lose the terms $\lceil \log n \rceil(1-\frac 1p)$ and $-\frac 1p$.  If $n$ is rather large $\log n$ is *much* smaller.  For example, using base $2$ logs, if $n \approx 1,000,000, \log n \approx 20$.  Similarly, the $-\frac 1p$ is a factor $n$ smaller than the $\frac np$ term.  Often it is from an expansion in powers of the small term.  Here we are led to expect that the fractional errors will be of order $\frac pn$.

A more explicit example that comes up frequently is $(1+x)^n \approx 1+nx$ when $x \ll 1$.  We can expand it explicitly and get
$$(1+x)^n=1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}2x^2+\frac {n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}x^3+\ldots$$
We see if $nx \ll 1$ each successive term is roughly a factor $nx$ smaller than the previous one.  If we can accept that much error we can often simplify the calculation significantly.

Comment: I think is most interesting to know how he derived the $n/p$ in the first place, assuming it is not just a guess and check. From what i understand from your answer, are you saying we can use an asymptotic expansion (in the left side) to do this?

Comment: I indicate how we justify the $\frac np$ as being close and what the approximate error is.  Without the context I do not know the motivation.  Asymptotic expansions are often what we use.

Comment: I still don't know exactly the purpose of that approximation in particular, but the LHS is an upper bound on the time for a simulation on a parallel computer ($n$ is input size and $p$ is number of processors). Comment aside, i did an expansion "at infinity" using Mathematica with `Series[Log[n] + (n - Log[n])/p, {n, Infinity, 2}]`, it gives $n/p$ as the first term.

Answer (score 0):

I would generally take these sorts of statements as being a variant of the concept of limit. In this case, if we take "much bigger" to mean additively larger, then it means

$\forall (\epsilon>0) \exists D: (n > D+p) \rightarrow |LHS-\frac n p|<\epsilon$

In other words, no matter how small your margin of error is, it's possible to guarantee to get within that margin of error by making sure that the amount by which $n$ is greater than $p$ is above some minimum value $D$.

equivalently,

$\forall (\epsilon>0) \exists D: (n-p> D) \rightarrow |LHS-\frac n p|<\epsilon$

That is, as long as $n-p$ is above some minimum value $D$, your error is less that $\epsilon$.

If "much bigger" means multiplicatively larger, then

$\forall (\epsilon>0) \exists R: (n > Rp) \rightarrow |LHS-\frac n p|<\epsilon$

(If you're not familiar with the acronym, LHS means "Left Hand Side", i.e. the stuff to the left of the "approximately equal" symbol.)

Comment: But how he derived $n/p$?